# Setting data returned by useQuery as state

Tags: react-native, expo, apollo, react-apollo

I have been using client.query to get data from my database and setting states using useState.

Here's an example:

```
const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]); 

client.query({ query: GET_VIDEOS })
 .then(response => {
        setVideos(response.data.videos); 
})
```

However, this does not load 100% of the time. Usually, it doesn't load when I load the app for the first time in a while. I typically have to reboot in these situations.

This issue makes me want to look into useQuery instead of client.query.

However, the examples in the documentation only show how we can use useQuery to make direct changes in the components.

Example:

```
function Dogs({ onDogSelected }) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);

  if (loading) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  return (
    <select name="dog" onChange={onDogSelected}>
      {data.dogs.map(dog => (
        <option key={dog.id} value={dog.breed}>
          {dog.breed}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

However, I don't want to make changes to the components right now. I would much rather query the data and then set the queried data as a state, using useState.

How would I best accomplish this? One idea that I had was to create a component that returns null but queries the data. It would look something like this:

```
function Videos() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_VIDEOS);

  if (loading) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  setVideos(data); 

  return null;
}
```

I was curious to hear what are best practices for such situations.

Answer (score 2):

react-apollo's `useQuery` has an `onCompleted` as one of its options, so you can use it like

```
const { loading, error } = useQuery(GET_VIDEOS, {
  onCompleted: (data) => setVideos(data)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the best practise would be to use the data directly, without setting the state.

you have only showed the calling of `setState`, somewhere in your component the `video` state variable is used right?

pass the fetched data directly there. you need not call "setVideos" to trigger the change. whenever the query result is changed the UI will be changed accordingly.

There is `useLazyQuery` if your use case is not to fetch the data upfront.